# Unable to add 'Test' of one JIRA project in the Test Cycle of another JIRA project

Tags: jira, jira-plugin, jira-agile

We have added a Zephyr Test Case management Add-on in my JIRA Software. We have created some 'Tests' in one JIRA project(Master_Project) and created a search filter in that project itself. Now we are trying to access/add the "Test" of Master_Project to the test cycle of another JIRA project using the search filter.

We are facing a problem while adding the "Test" in the test cycle to a 'Test Cycle'. We are getting the following error message:

[image]

Does anyone face such problem? Can you please suggest, what could be the solution or How can we resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Adding tests belonging to Project1 to a test cycle in Project2 does not currently work and I don't know if Zephyr plan to fix this at all. The tests and the cycle have to be in the same project.